# Cannot Interlocked.Exchange object except for types already declared in its overloads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm testing with threads for my project. While testing, I realizes that we cannot assign variable in threads. After that I found a solution: using `Interlocked` class.

I tested it with `int`, it works really well. But as soon as I change it to a class, it throws me:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I was expecting a line with "Class" in the output.

Can anyone explain me what is going on here?

Code (assuming that the code is in the `Program` class and every namespace needed is declared):

```cs
static Class i;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ModThread));
    thread.Start();

    Console.WriteLine(i.ToString());
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void ModThread ()
{
    Interlocked.Exchange(ref i, new Class());
}

class Class { }
```

Comment: `i` is `null`. This is expected behavior. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.exchange?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Interlocked_Exchange__1___0____0_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primitive values are never null. They have some default value.

Classes that have not been initialized can be null. So in this line

```
Interlocked.Exchange(ref i, new Class());
```

Your ref is null because i is not initialized here: `static Class i;`

Try your code with `static Class i = new Class();`

Check documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.exchange?view=netframework-4.8

```
public static object Exchange (ref object location1, object value);
```

> Exceptions
>   ArgumentNullException
>   The address of location1 is a null pointer.

**Edit 1**

To see the updated value, make the main thread sleep for a bit and then print the outcome.

```
    thread.Start();
    Thread.Sleep(100);
```

You can't control the execution order when you are using threads. So what happens is:

1. The second thread is told to start
2. The first thread prints the current value
3. The second thread copies the value

With the Sleep command, we tell the first thread to wait a bit so the second one is able to change the value before the first one `WriteLine`

Comment: I don't mean it. I was asking: Why did I not become an instance of Class? Also, the exception was thrown in the 8th line of the code.

Comment: It didn't because null points nowhere. Where would the value be copied to? There is no reference assigned to i when you exchange the value.

Comment: Now I changed the code, but it outputs 1 instead of 2.

Comment: The values changes after you writeline.

Comment: Check the updated answer. Imagine that the second thread does something very complicated and time consuming. You wouldn't expect it to finish before the first thread continues, otherwise what's the point of threads? In your case the first thread is just faster than the second.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras "Where would the value be copied to?" it doesn't copy object to address, it copies address of an object to address. Think about it as copying into a variable. So copying address into a variable that was pointing to NULL should be fine